# Can I specify template to use with the_permalink?

Tags: permalinks

Can I specify a template to use with the_permalink()?

Why I need this: when they click a link from a certain page, I want to show that user a different template (extra content) on the linked page.

Comment: So, if I click a link generated in one specific page in your WordPress installation and printed by `the_permalink()`, you want me to see a different page than if I just enter the URL manually, or get there via any other page?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`the_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink) function links to the **single post view** for the given post-type. As per the [**Template Hierarchy**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), the page used to render the single post view is **`single.php`**.

So, if you want to modify the template used to render the page when clicking `the_permalink()`, create/modify `single.php`, or for a specific post-type, create/modify `single-{posttype}.php`.

If you want to reference the referring page, you may want to look at hooking into `template_redirect`, and referencing `$REFERRER`, or something.

Comment: Thank you, Chip, referrer worked. Not entirely safe, but good enough for my purpose. Final code:

`<?php $ref=getenv('HTTP_REFERER');
 if (strpos($ref,"domain.com/page")>0) : ?>

 <p>content for those who came from /page.</p>

 <?php else : ?>

  <p>normal content</p>

   <?php endif; ?>`